# Is there an equivalent to AutoRenewTimeout(TimeSpan) for ASB transport?

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

We are using the (non-legacy) Azure Service Bus transport. Is there an equivalent to `AutoRenewTimeout(TimeSpan)` that we can use? And if not (as the docs suggest) how does the transport handle long-running processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to AutoRenewTimeout(TimeSpan) that we can use?

The short answer is "no". The legacy transport included the option of [auto-renewing the lock](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/legacy/message-lock-renewal) which was not introduced in the new transport. The rationale for that was simply due to some issues with the functionality. First, it is not a guaranteed operation. It's a client-side initiated operation that can fail and sometimes does, leaving users with questions how did that happen. Second, it encourages to create code where handlers are running for a long time, which is not something NServiceBus is designed for. Instead, the recommendation is to take long processing outside of NServiceBus code. There's a [sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/azure-service-bus-long-running/) that demonstrates exactly that: Long-running operations with Azure Service Bus Transport.